# how to wait until ControlTemplate applied to the control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I have added a function in my CustomControl called `AddColumn`

```
 public void AddColumn(string ColumnHeader)
 {
     Grid MainGrid = this.Template.FindName("MainGrid", this) as Grid;
     Border Header = this.Template.FindName("header", this) as Border;

     if (MainGrid != null)
     {

         MainGrid.Children.Add(HeaderText);
         // ...

         MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = 
         MainGrid.Children.Add(...);
         // ...
         GridSplitter Splitter = new GridSplitter() { HorizontalAlignment 
         MainGrid.Children.Add(Splitter);
         // ...
         Grid.SetColumnSpan(Header, ColumnCounter-1);
     }
 }
```

In this method, as you can see, there are two calls of ControlTemplate Items.

I can't use this method before Templating job done. my ControlTemplate is global and I don't know where should I wait for it.

Can I wait or apply ControlTemplate in a correct way to be able to call this method whenever I wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that your control should override `OnApplyTemplate` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate(v=vs.110).aspx))

> Derived classes of FrameworkElement can use this method as a notification for a variety of possible scenarios:
>
> - You can call your own implementation of code that builds the remainder of an element visual tree.
> - You can run code that relies on the visual tree from templates having been applied, such as obtaining references to named elements that came from a template.
> - You can introduce services that only make sense to exist after the visual tree from templates is complete.
> - You can set states and properties of elements within the template that are dependent on other factors. For instance, property values might only be discoverable by knowing the parent element, or when a specific derived class uses a common template.

Without knowing your use case though; I'd strongly suspect this is an XY problem and that you really want some sort of bound `ItemsControl` instead.

Comment: Actually i forced to write my own DataGrid, I have extended `HeaderedContentControl` class an i added my row container and column container. i have written a ControlTemplate for my own DataGrid and i Added an `AddColumn` method to the controls class. this method works with my template and i must wait until template loaded completely. so i cant call this method in MainWindow`s Constructor because ControlTemplate doesn't applied to the control at this time

Comment: @RezaNoei You could store up pending requests; then process them in `OnApplyTemplate` or just do the calls in `OnLoaded` for the window. That said; even on a *custom* data grid I would expect this stuff to come in through XAML or a binding; not a manual call in code-behind.

Comment: Thanks. my grid is based on grid.row and grid.column properties. and i don't know how automatically set grid.Column and grid.Row in XAML.

Comment: @RezaNoei Those properties are bindable just like anything else; or you can set them with `Grid.SetRow/Grid.SetColumn` from your control.

Comment: for Rows i have an ItemsControl which is bind-able. but for columns i have a problem. i must observe add function to the header cols and whenever a user want to add a new column i must add an Grid.SetRow/Grid.SetColumn for this call. i don't know how to this.

Comment: I think, my knowledge about WPF is in progress and i must rewrite this later. 
thank you @BradleyDotNET